# WCHAR [256] as WCHAR ** i.e., Iterating over array strings vs Iterating over just one string

Tags: c

I am working on a code where I want to iterate over array of strings. But sometimes I might have to just iterate over one string and this string is of the form WCHAR[256] Now the question is how can I treat WCHAR[256] as LPCWSTR* so that I don't have to treat WCHAR[256] as a special case when iterating. Below is the code sample.

Please let me know if there is any other elegant solution here?

```
WCHAR BranchName[MAX_PATH];
BOOLEAN AllBranches;

WCHAR* DefaultBranches[] = {
    L"branch1",
    L"branch2",
    L"branch3",
};

INT
wmain (
    _In_ INT Argc,
    _In_ WCHAR **Argv
    )
{

    WCHAR **Branch; // Pointer to array of strings. How can I make this point to WCHAR[256]?
    UINT Count;
    UINT Index;

    ParseArguments(Argc, Argv); // Set AllBranches to true if Custom branch is not provided

    if (AllBranches) {  // If all branches is true
        Branch = DefaultBranches;
        Count = ARRAYSIZE(DefaultBranches);
    } else { // BranchName containing the custom branch name provided as cmd line arg
        // How can BranchName be assigned to Branch pointer so that iterating
        // over just one string do not become a special case?
        Branch =  ???  <-- NOT SURE HOW TO DO IT!!!
        Count = 1;
    }

    // I want this loop to iterate over array string pointers and also with
    // one string
    for (Index = 0; Index < Count; Index += 1) {
        // do some thing with *Branch and I don't want to duplicate it
        // when iterating over array of strings vs iterating over a string
        Branch++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you intend `WCHAR** DefaultBranches[] ...` where you are using a array of pointer-to-pointer to wide chars? Removing a `'*'` would make more sense. (leaving an array-of-pointers)

Comment: Sorry I fixed it...

Comment: *"How can I make this point to WCHAR[256]?"*  `Branch = DefaultBranches;` is fine. They are type-compatible. Why? [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) (the array-of-pointers is converted to a pointer to the first string on access -- which is `WCHAR**`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

```
WCHAR * BranchNameArr [] = { BranchName };
Branch = BranchNameArr;
```

or

```
WCHAR * BranchNamePtr =  BranchName;
Branch = & BranchNamePtr;
```

are fine.